# Multiple choice question regarding the ideal of $C[0, 1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $C[0,\ 1]$ be the ring of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,\ 1]$, with
addition and multiplication deﬁned pointwise. For any subset $S$ of $C[0,\ 1]$ let
$$Z(S) =\{f \in C[0,\ 1] \mid f(x) = 0,\ \forall x \in S \}.$$
 Then which of the following
statements are true?

(a) If $Z(S)$ is an ideal in $C[0,\ 1]$ then $S$ is closed in $[0,\ 1]$.
(b) If $Z(S)$ is a maximal ideal then $S$ has only one point.
(c) If $S$ has only one point then $Z(S)$ is a maximal ideal.

---

I can not understand how to proceed in this problem.Can I get some help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(a) As already pointed out, $Z(S)=Z(\overline{S})$ hence we can assume that $S$ is closed.

(b) Assume that $S$ contains $a\neq b$. Then $Z(S)\subset Z(\{a,b\})$. We can construct a continuous function which vanishes at $a$ but not at $b$.

(c) If $I\supsetneq Z(S)$, then it contains $f_0$ which does not vanish at $s_0$, where $\{s_0\}=S$. Using compactness of the unit interval, we can find $g_0\in I$ such that $g(x)\gt 0$ for each $x$.

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate how statement 1 is true?

Comment: Sir, Can't we consider $S$ to be an open interval  $(1/2, 1/3)$ then too $Z(S)$ is an ideal and hence statement 1 is false?

Answer (score 1):

if $f$ is continuous and $f(A)=0$ then $f(\bar A)=0$ although this implies the ideals correspond to closed sets, it also has the consequence that the ideal specified by a closed set $C$ can equally well be specified as the set of functions which are zero on any dense subset of $C$.

the remaining parts of the question depends on the fact that the sets consisting of a single point are the minimal nonempty closed sets.